# Sci-fi novel about teenagers at war

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to track down a (might be sci-fi) novel I once read as a kid. While I don't remember the name, I remember a few scenes in and about the book:

- A father who is a king (also a psychic/telekinetic who regularly changes his appearance when meeting his subjects)
- Rules over a giant city, which had gates at the four cardinal points ( I remember this being important for some reason)
- A rebellious son who is trying to overthrow the king through a war.
- The son is a powerful psychic/telekinetic himself
- Leads a army of teenagers against the king
- Most of the teenagers in the army had a tattoo on them saying "Grow Old, Why?" or something similar. I sort of remember this being of certain significance.
- The army may also have been broken down into four as well.
- They used to recruit other teenagers to the their army by travelling to other "realms?" and conquering them?
- In one scene the son enters a room, which seems to have several artefacts, one of which being a mirror. All the artefacts needed to be in the room for the mirror to activate, and it also lead to another special realm?.....supposedly one where the king gained his powers?....the son walks through the mirror as well and gains something before his final confrontation with the father.
- This may have been part of a series of books, but this was the only one in the series that I read

More Information (Update)

- One of leaders of the 4 armies was a girl that the son had a crush on, and finally manages to hook up with part way through the book
- There may be another faction of (green) aliens involved.
- I think it was a part of the king's duty to keep them pacified by giving them occasional offerings so they would not invade his realm. (I think a part of that tribute was givng them a certain number of psychics). They may have powered their ships using technology powered by psychics.
- The king's city may have also been powered by technology based on psychics.

This information may not be 100% accurate as its been almost 20 years since I read it, but hopefully it helps someone figure out which book I meant. (Also I may have mixed information from 2 books?, I am not sure)

Comment: Can you remember anything about the appearance of the cover? Was the book hard or paperback?

Comment: @regionalsky it definitely was a paperback.....and I also remember for some reason, all the teenagers in the army had their hair styled into mohawks....I have a vague recollection of the cover having a guy with a mohawk (the mohawk may or may not have been pink or green) may have been chasing something/someone.....

Comment: Was there a "side" we were on? Were we supposed to root for the king or the son or both/neither?

Comment: @Kitkat, I am not sure about this, but in the end, the king stops keeping the aliens pacified, who then attack the city. The king and the son are forced to team up, and repel the invasion, after which he gives the son control of the city in a final converation before jumping back into the "mirror". Although I am not sure about the "team up" part. But the son was the main character, the story was from his perspective.